# How have null value inside basic_string in c++

Tags: c++, string, null

Is there a way to have and process null value inside `std::basic_string`?

Sometimes the string sequence being passed has null values. For example below code outputs 1234,5678 instead of whole string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
int main ()
{
   int length;
   std::string str = "1234,5678\000,ABCD,EFG#";
   std::cout << "length"<<str.c_str();
}
```

I need to get the complete string.

Comment: @Manwal That would be the `c_str()` member function of the standard C++ string class. What does it look like?

Comment: Can you use C++ 14? Also I hate C strings D=

Answer (score 6):

First, you'll have to tell the string constructor the size; it can only determine the size if the input is null-terminated. Something like this would work:

```
std::string str("1234,5678\000,ABCD,EFG#", sizeof("1234,5678\000,ABCD,EFG#")-1);
```

There's no particularly nice way to avoid the duplication; you could declare a local array

```
char c_str[] = "1234,5678\000,ABCD,EFG#"; // In C++11, perhaps 'auto const & c_str = "...";'
std::string str(c_str, sizeof(c_str)-1);
```

which might have a run-time cost; or you could use a macro; or you could build the string in pieces

```
std::string str = "1234,5678";
str += '\0';
str += ",ABCD,EFG#";
```

Finally, stream the string itself (for which the size is known) rather than extracting a c-string pointer (for which the size will be determined by looking for a null terminator):

```
std::cout << "length" << str;
```

UPDATE: as pointed out in the comments, C++14 adds a suffix for `basic_string` literals:

```
std::string str = "1234,5678\000,ABCD,EFG#"s;
                                           ^
```

which, by my reading of the draft standard, should work even if there is an embedded null character.

Comment: There's also the `basic_string` literal suffix `s` in C++14, the latest libc++ and libstdc++ both support it.

Comment: @user657267: Thanks, I'm not yet familiar with C++14. Do you know whether it works if there's a null character in the literal string?

Comment: @user657267: I guess it does, since the operator is passed the length of the literal.

Comment: I believe so, can't say I've actually used it yet and for some reason gcc 4.9.1 isn't finding it...should work in theory though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `std::string(std::initalizer_list<char> il)` it's just a little bit of a pain in the neck:

```
string str{'1', '2', '3', '4', ',', '5', '6', '7', '8', '\0', '0', '0', ',', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', ',', 'E', 'F', 'G', '#'};
cout << "length: " << str.size() << ": " << str;
```

Outputs:

> length: 22: 1234,567800,ABCD,EFG#